# SSL free, hosting App infinityfree not working

Tags: ssl-certificate, web-hosting

[error when verify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPnhC.png)

[Link is working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTIfy.png)
I use hosting App infinityfree and sslforfree.com
I met a problems when trying to verify domain for a free SSL. I do not know why it still has errors even though the link is working. I tried many times but can't solve it. Please help me. thanks a lot

Comment: In your **error when verify**, you can see that the certificate provider is getting some HTML, but it is expecting what you see in **Link is working**. you should check why it is not returning the correct content

Comment: Is there any rule where the hosting provider returns different content to bot base on user-agent?

Comment: Maybe, actually I thought like you before but i am not sure. I use App InfinityFree hosting and not know much about that. tks for you help